# Passing a class type in a stubbed method for mockito

Tags: java, junit

I have a dependency method which looks something like this:

```
class Dependency {
    public CustomObject myMethod(int a, int b, Class<T> classType) {
    ... 
    }
}
```

I am writing a unit test for a method which calls this dependency

My test class looks something like:

```
public class MyTest {

@Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Mock private MyDependency
@Test 
    public void testCallingMyDependency() {
        when(MyDependency.myMethod(any(), any(), any()).thenReturn(new CustObject());
}
```

Firstly, this throws a null pointer exception in the line for the when statement. Then I see exceptions like

```
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
    [junit] -> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    [junit] -> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    [junit] -> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    [junit]
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the `int` arguments, you'll need to use the `anyInt` matcher.